# Help optimize this query with a huge IN statement

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have an insert that uses a condition checking for a NOT IN. There are about 230k rows in the NOT IN subquery.

```
INSERT INTO Validate.ItemError (ItemId, ErrorId, DateCreated) 
(
    SELECT ItemId, 10, GetUTCDate() 
    FROM Validate.Item 
    INNER JOIN Refresh.Company 
    ON Validate.Item.IMCompanyId = Refresh.Company.IMCompanyId 
    WHERE Refresh.Company.CompanyId = 14 
    AND 
    (
        IMAccountId IS NULL OR NOT IMAccountId IN
        (
            SELECT RA.IMAccountId 
            FROM Refresh.Account RA 
            INNER JOIN Refresh.BalancePool BP 
            ON RA.BalancePoolId = BP.BalancePoolId 
            WHERE BP.CompanyId = 14
        )
    )
)
```

When I run this as-is it takes about 30+ minutes (yikes!).  The number of values in the Validate.Item table could be anywhere from 150 rows to over 200k, so you can see how this might be a pain.

There are indices on all the relevant fields in the tables, and none are excessively fragmented.

My first thought was to do this in pieces, and throw it into a WHILE loop:

```
DECLARE @StartId int, @EndId int, @MaxId int

SELECT @MaxId = MAX(AccountId) FROM Refresh.Account
SET @StartId = 1
SET @EndId = 1000

WHILE (@StartId < @MaxId)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Validate.ItemError (ItemId, ErrorId, DateCreated) 
    (
        SELECT ItemId, 10, GetUTCDate() 
        FROM Validate.Item 
        INNER JOIN Refresh.Company 
        ON Validate.Item.IMCompanyId = Refresh.Company.IMCompanyId 
        WHERE Refresh.Company.CompanyId = 14 
        AND 
        (
            IMAccountId IS NULL  
            OR NOT IMAccountId IN  
            (
                SELECT RA.IMAccountId 
                FROM Refresh.Account RA 
                INNER JOIN Refresh.BalancePool BP 
                ON RA.BalancePoolId = BP.BalancePoolId 
                WHERE BP.CompanyId = 14 
                AND RA.AccountId BETWEEN @StartId AND @EndId
            )
        )
    )
    SET @StartId = @StartId + 1000
    SET @EndId = @EndId + 1000
END
```

Doing it this way nets me a time of about a minute per loop; multiply that by 230 times and we have an even more ridiculous number.

Please tell me you guys have a better idea how to optimize this. Without this one query, the entire process only takes 8 seconds; it's just the sheer size of the Refresh.Account table that throws everything into chaos.

TIA!

Valkyrie

Comment: You might have poorly optimised/indexed tables which you might want to tackle first.

Comment: @Kragen: How did you indent the code? any tool?

Comment: Could you please post the query plan as it is now?

Comment: I think that it is possible that some indices get used stupidly. Please do EXPLAIN ANALYZE (your query) and see which parts take a long time. How many rows are there in the subquery after IN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does using `NOT EXISTS` help here?

```
(SELECT ItemId, 10, GetUTCDate() 
FROM Validate.Item INNER JOIN Refresh.Company ON 
Validate.Item.IMCompanyId = Refresh.Company.IMCompanyId 
WHERE Refresh.Company.CompanyId = 14 
AND (IMAccountId IS NULL  OR  NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 RA.IMAccountId FROM 
Refresh.Account RA INNER JOIN Refresh.BalancePool BP 
ON RA.BalancePoolId = BP.BalancePoolId WHERE BP.CompanyId = 14 AND 
RA.IMAcccountID = Validate.Item.IMAccountId)))
```

I am not sure, if the query is correct.

But, I am using `NOT EXISTS` along with `TOP 1` inside the subquery.
Also, the subquery limits the record by adding an additional `AND RA.IMAcccountID = Validate.Item.IMAccountId`.

EDIT: I hope you get the idea of what I am trying to do.
Instead of checking it against all rows inside Refresh.Account, I am limiting the rows and trying to find atleast 1 matching row with matching IMAccountID - which should not be existing as per your original query (that uses `NOT IN ...`).

Comment: ALL of you rock!  This took me to a sub 1-second query, and is EXACTLY what I needed.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `OR` condition.

It adds a fullscan and prevents the optimizer from using an `ANTI JOIN` which it would use otherwise.

This query returns the same:

```
SELECT  ItemId, 10, GetUTCDate() 
FROM    Validate.Item 
INNER JOIN
        Refresh.Company 
ON      Validate.Item.IMCompanyId = Refresh.Company.IMCompanyId 
WHERE   Refresh.Company.CompanyId = 14 
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  RA.IMAccountId 
        FROM    Refresh.Account RA 
        INNER JOIN
                Refresh.BalancePool BP 
        ON      RA.BalancePoolId = BP.BalancePoolId 
        WHERE   BP.CompanyId = 14
                AND RA.IMAccounID = Validate.Item.IMAccountId
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT EXISTS instead:

```
...OR  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
Refresh.Account RA INNER JOIN Refresh.BalancePool BP 
ON RA.BalancePoolId = BP.BalancePoolId WHERE BP.CompanyId = 14 AND RA.IMAccountId = xxx.IMAccountId)))
```

The subquery following EXISTS will only return the first record satisfying criteria. (Remember to replace xxx with the alias of the right table)

Comment: Virtually the same as shahkalpesh, but "TOP 1" is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing a "not in", could you just do a left join to the relevant table and check for null keys?  Not sure if the query is 100% correct:

```
INSERT INTO Validate.ItemError (ItemId, ErrorId, DateCreated) 
SELECT ItemId, 10, GetUTCDate() 
FROM Validate.Item 
INNER JOIN Refresh.Company ON Validate.Item.IMCompanyId = Refresh.Company.IMCompanyId 
LEFT JOIN Refresh.Account
  INNER JOIN Refresh.BalancePool BP ON BP.BalancePoolId = RA.BalancePoolId
ON Refresh.Account.IMAccountId = Validate.Item.IMAccountId 
WHERE Refresh.Company.CompanyId = 14 
AND Validate.Item.IMAccountId IS NULL OR Refresh.Account.IMAccountId IS NULL
```